# Underscore where filter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use Underscore's `where` to filter an array of objects, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to filter multiple values for the same key. For example:

```
var itemsArr = [{name:"foo", color:"red"}, {name:"bar", color:"blue"}, {name:"bob", color:"yellow"}];
```

I'm trying to get it to return an array off all items with color `red` AND all items with color `blue`... Is this possible? I've tried

```
tempArr = _.where(itemsArr, {color:["red", "blue"]});
```

but that didn't work. If I have to just use `_.filter` and write out my own predicate I will, but I was just wondering if anyone else had tried to do this and found a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) combination:

```
_.filter(itemsArr, function(item, index) {
  return _.contains(["red", "blue"], item.color);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This turned out to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How can I extend the filter to filter for `name` also? Say `_.contains(["red", "blue"], item.color);` **and** `_.contains(["foo", "bob"], item.name);` ?

Comment: _.contains(["red", "blue"], item.color) && _.contains(["foo", "bob"], item.name)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function:

```
_.filter(itemsArr,function(itm){return itm.color=='red' || itm.color=='blue'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you run _.where twice and concat the two resulting arrays?

```
tempArr = _.where(itemsArr, {color: "red"}).concat(_.where(itemsArr, {color: "blue"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
 var itemsArr = [{name:"foo", color:"red"}, {name:"bar", color:"blue"}, {name:"bob", color:"red"}];
 var filter = ["red","blue"];
 var data = {};
 _.each(filter, function (item) { 
       data[item] = true; 
   });

 var returnData = _.filter(itemsArr, function (item) {
                    return data[item.color];
                 });

 console.log(returnData)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#where):

> Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the **key-value pairs** listed in properties.

You can also look at the [source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) if you'd like. Under the hood, `where` uses `isMatch`:

```
_.isMatch = function(object, attrs) {
    var keys = _.keys(attrs), length = keys.length;
    if (object == null) return !length;
    var obj = Object(object);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        if (attrs[key] !== obj[key] || !(key in obj)) return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Since you cannot have two identical keys, you cannot do what you would like. I would use `filter`, as you suggest.